# Problems with mod function to find remainder

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner and having problems with my code I don't quite understand. The first option in my `switch` menu is not working and I have tried numerous tweaks to no avail. I've removed the `if...else` statement, altered the "second" variable between `constant = 0` and not constant, a few other things as well.

This code is supposed to reverse the digits in an integer. If the integer is less than 10, i.e. 2, the 2 becomes 20. I'm not achieving anything close to that.

```
                cout << "Please enter a number between 0 and 99\n";
                cin >> num;
                if (num < 9)
                    num *= 10;
                else
                    num += 0;
                while (num !=0)
                {
                    remainder = num%10;
                    second = remainder*10 + remainder;
                    num /= 10;
                }
                cout << num << " reverses to make " << second << endl;
```

Comment: What first option? What `switch` menu?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace this:

```
if (num < 9)
                    num *= 10;
                else
                    num += 0;
                while (num !=0)
                {
                    remainder = num%10;
                    second = remainder*10 + remainder;
                    num /= 10;
                }
```

With this

```
if (num <= 9)
                    second = 10*num;
                else
                    remainder = num%10;
                    second = remainder*10 + trunc(num/10);
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some problems I can see with your code for what you are trying to achieve.

Even if your number entered is lower than 10:

```
if (num < 9)
   num *= 10;
```

Your code still goes inside the while loop:

```
while (num !=0)
{
    remainder = num%10;
    second = remainder*10 + remainder;
    num /= 10;
}
```

For example. Lets say you entered 2, after it goes through the first `if` statement, it'll be 20. However, it'll go inside the while loop after the operations, it'll be 22.

The following line of your code does absolutely nothing. Hence, it won't make a difference whether you get rid of it or not.

```
else
   num += 0;
```

For what you are trying to achieve, converting the `num` to string, reversing it, and turning it back to integer would be less complicated and easier to implement.

Hope it helped!